# MongoDB lookup issues with performance php

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch data from mongoDB using lookup

collections companies

```
{
 "id" : 1,
 "company_id" : 2,
  "user_group" : 1,
 "company_name" : "xyz",
 "created_on" : "00-00-0000"
}
```

collection users

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "company_id" : 1,
  "user_group" : 1,
  "name" : "abcd",
  "email" : "abcd@abcd.abcd"
 }



{
  "id" : 1,
  "company_id" : 2,
  "active": 1,
   "user_group" : 1,
  "name" : "efgh",
  "email" : "efgh@efgh.efgh"
}
```

Query used to fetch data using php

```
$collection->aggregate([
        ['$match' => ['company_id' => 2]],
            ['$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'users',
                'localField' => 'user_group',
                'foreignField' => 'user_group',
                'as' => 'company_users',
            ]],
            ['$unwind' => ['path' => '$company_users', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true]],
            ['$match' => ['$and' => [['company_users.company_id' => 2], ['company_users.active' => 1]]]],
            ['$project' => [
                '_id' => false,
                'company_id' => true,
                'user_group' => true,
                'company_users.name' => true,
                'company_users.email' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Query is working correctly but takes more time to retrieve data if document is greater than 1000

Comment: do you have indexes? (particularly on `company_id` on companies and `user_group` on users)

Comment: Please provide MongoDB version and indexes information on your collections.

Comment: @Akrion i have done index like this is it correct    ensureIndex(['company_id' => 1]) in companies and user but there is no change in result

Comment: @kmdreko i am using mongodb version 3.4

Comment: can you update your mongodb version to 3.6?

Comment: It is not possible now is there any draw back in mongodb 3.4 for lookup i am new to mongodb @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: `$unwind` is the most expensive stage here so if you use  newer mongodb version [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) 
 syntax you can filter(`$match`)  out the documents within the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline, which makes execution faster

Comment: Is it possible to use mongodb like relational DB

Comment: Yes and that's what `$lookup` does

Comment: Ok so multiple lookup will not affect performance is it??..
Thanks for all Your comments :)

Comment: No `$lookup` will never be costly if there is always a `$match`ing criteria